# Hide devise Guest users in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

In my rails app am using Devise for authentication and using Rails Admin as an admin dashboard. To save users location without signing them in the app am using Devise's Guest User, it all works well,but the issue is my rails admin User tab is filled with Guest Users, is there any way to hide the guest users only from rails admin users tab and show only the users who have all the credentials.

Comment: Are your guest users being created with a "guest" role or something? Please post the code that creates these guest users.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to define a `verifed` scope for your `User`

```
#app/models/user.rb
scope :verified, -> { where(guest: false) }
```

And then, configure your Rails admin for User model like below

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model User do
    list do
      scopes [:verified]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi @quyetdc thanks for the help it worked, but only on localhost, when i pushed the code on heroku nothing happened do you know why that happened?

Comment: Really? Are u sure u pushed all the updates from local to heroku? @peter

Comment: yes i also performed a rake assets:precompile before pushing